# ng click to work on a new tab as well as the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need `ng` click to work on a new tab as well a self tab .The url is dynamic depending on a condition .

Html:

```
<a ng-href="{{myPathVariable }} "  ng-click=" GoToThemes()" class="shift-left">Themes</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.GoToThemes = function () {

    if ($sessionStorage.CategoryObj == null || $sessionStorage.CategoryObj == undefined || jQuery.isEmptyObject($sessionStorage.CategoryObj) || $scope.order.CategoryObj == undefined || $scope.order.CategoryObj == null || jQuery.isEmptyObject($scope.order.CategoryObj))
    {
        $scope.myPathVariable="/featured/themes";

    }
    else {
          $scope.myPathVariable = "/" + $sessionStorage.CategoryObj.Alias.replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, "-").toLowerCase() + "/themes";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you can use an expression for the target attribute:

```
<a target="{{conditionToBlank?'_blank':'_self'}}" ng-href="{{myPathVariable }} "  ng-click=" GoToThemes()" class="shift-left">Themes</a>
```